# Result of getting next 12 months in Javascript is messed up

Tags: javascript, date

I have the following code for generating a list of the next 12 months (inclusive), starting from today's date:

```
function DateUtilFunctions() {
    var self = this;

    var monthNames = new Array();

    monthNames[0] = "January";
    monthNames[1] = "February";
    monthNames[2] = "March";
    monthNames[3] = "April";
    monthNames[4] = "May";
    monthNames[5] = "June";
    monthNames[6] = "July";
    monthNames[7] = "August";
    monthNames[8] = "September";
    monthNames[9] = "October";
    monthNames[10] = "November";
    monthNames[11] = "December";

    self.getNext12MonthNamesWithYear = function () {
        var months = new Array();
        var today = new Date(Date());

        var loopDate = new Date();
        loopDate.setTime(today.valueOf());

        var todayPlus12Months = new Date(today.setMonth(today.getMonth() + 12));

        while (loopDate.valueOf() < todayPlus12Months.valueOf()) {
            alert(loopDate);
            alert(loopDate.getMonth());
            var month = monthNames[loopDate.getMonth()];


            months.push(month + ' ' + loopDate.getFullYear());
            loopDate.setMonth(loopDate.getMonth() + 1);
        }

        return months;
    };
}
```

The result of calling `getNext12MonthNamesWithYear()` is:

- "May 2012"
- "July 2012"
- "August 2012"
- "May 2012"
- "July 2012"
- "August 2012"
- "September 2012"
- "October 2012"
- "November 2012"
- "December 2012"
- "January 2013"
- "February 2013"
- "March 2013"
- "April 2013"
- "May 2013"

As you can, the start of the list is a bit weird, in that "June" is missing, plus "May", "July" and "August" appear twice.

Naturally I;m doing something very wrong here; could someone please help me out?

EDIT:

Based on micadelli's comment, here is the solution I used:

```
function DateUtilFunctions() {
    var self = this;

    var monthNames = new Array();

    monthNames[0] = "January";
    monthNames[1] = "February";
    monthNames[2] = "March";
    monthNames[3] = "April";
    monthNames[4] = "May";
    monthNames[5] = "June";
    monthNames[6] = "July";
    monthNames[7] = "August";
    monthNames[8] = "September";
    monthNames[9] = "October";
    monthNames[10] = "November";
    monthNames[11] = "December";

    self.getNext12MonthNamesWithYear = function () {
        var months = new Array();
        var today = new Date();
        var tmpDate = new Date();
        var tmpYear = tmpDate.getFullYear();
        var tmpMonth = tmpDate.getMonth();
        var monthLiteral;

        for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            tmpDate.setMonth(tmpMonth + i);
            tmpDate.setFullYear(tmpYear);
            monthLiteral = monthNames[tmpMonth];

            months.push(monthLiteral + ' ' + tmpYear);

            tmpYear = (tmpMonth == 11) ? tmpYear + 1 : tmpYear;
            tmpMonth = (tmpMonth == 11) ? 0 : tmpMonth + 1;
        }

        return months;
    };
}
```

Comment: Use a library like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting 'moment.js'. Although I have used a different approach, I will keep that js on my tools list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont see any reason why this wouldn't work

```
function DateUtilFunctions() {
   var self = this;

   var monthNames = new Array();

   monthNames[0] = "January";
   monthNames[1] = "February";
   monthNames[2] = "March";
   monthNames[3] = "April";
   monthNames[4] = "May";
   monthNames[5] = "June";
   monthNames[6] = "July";
   monthNames[7] = "August";
   monthNames[8] = "September";
   monthNames[9] = "October";
   monthNames[10] = "November";
   monthNames[11] = "December";

   self.getNext12MonthNamesWithYear = function () {
     var months = new Array();
     var today = new Date();
     var tmpDate = new Date();
     var tmpYear = tmpDate.getFullYear();
     var tmpMonth = tmpDate.getMonth();
     var monthLiteral;

     for (var i = 0 ; i < 12 ; i++) {
        tmpDate.setMonth(tmpMonth + i);
        tmpDate.setFullYear(tmpYear);
        monthLiteral = monthNames[tmpMonth];
        months.push(monthLiteral + ' ' + tmpYear);
        tmpMonth = (tmpMonth == 11) ? 0 : tmpMonth+1;
        tmpYear = (tmpMonth == 11) ? tmpYear+1 : tmpYear;
     }

     return months;
   };
}
```

**JS Bin**
http://jsbin.com/aqezom

Comment: I tried your solution - almost correct, except that "July 2012" appears twice.

Comment: I don't see any reason this would work. Can you explain what your code does?

Comment: unnecessarily complicated, IMHO

Answer (score 11):

Don't try to manipulate the `Date` object - just use it to get the initial values for month and year and then use simple arithmetic on the results:

```
function getNext12MonthNamesWithYear() {
    var now = new Date();
    var month = now.getMonth();
    var year = now.getFullYear();

    var names = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
                 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

    var res = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 13; ++i) {
        res.push(names[month] + ' ' + year);
        if (++month === 12) {
            month = 0;
            ++year;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/SQQdg/

Comment: May as well skip the counters and just do `names[(month + i) % 12]` and `year + (i / 12 | 0)`.

Comment: @minitech yeah, that would work, but I was going for simplicity and clarity.

Comment: @Alnitak - +1 Thanks for your suggestion, I really like the clarity.

Answer (score 9):

Here is my solution using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

**Next 12 Months**

```js
let months = [];
let monthsRequired = 12

for (let i = 1; i <= monthsRequired; i++) {
  months.push( moment().add(i, 'months').format('MMMM YYYY') )
}

console.log(months)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

**Just in case if you need previous 12 Months**

```js
let months = [];
let monthsRequired = 12

for (let i = monthsRequired; i >= 1; i--) {
  months.push( moment().subtract(i, 'months').format('MMMM YYYY') )
}

console.log(months)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working version. You can not perform setMonth directly if the value is more than 12. Also, there is no 31st for some of the months which results in unexpected results.
JS fiddle here [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gbsandeep/MKq68/)

```
    var monthNames = new Array();

    monthNames[0] = "January";
    monthNames[1] = "February";
    monthNames[2] = "March";
    monthNames[3] = "April";
    monthNames[4] = "May";
    monthNames[5] = "June";
    monthNames[6] = "July";
    monthNames[7] = "August";
    monthNames[8] = "September";
    monthNames[9] = "October";
    monthNames[10] = "November";
    monthNames[11] = "December";

var today = new Date();
var currentMonth = today.getMonth();
var i;
for (i = 0 ; i < 12 ; i++) {
    var newMonth = currentMonth + i;
    var newYear = newMonth > 11 ? today.getFullYear() + 1: today.getFullYear();
    newMonth = newMonth > 11? (newMonth - 12): newMonth;

    var newDate = new Date(newYear, newMonth, '1');

    console.log(monthNames[newDate.getMonth()] + ' ' + newDate.getFullYear());
}

​
```

Comment: unnecessarily complicated, IMHO

Answer (score 1):

I also needed a list of the last 12 months this is what I did:

```
var theMonths = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
var today = new Date();
var aMonth = today.getMonth();
var i;
for (i=0; i<12; i++) {
    document.writeln(theMonths[aMonth] + '<br>'); //here you can do whatever you want...
    aMonth++;
    if (aMonth > 11) {
        aMonth = 0;
    }
}
```